# Qual a diferença entre software, programa, aplicativo, app e sistema?

Tags: terminologia, engenharia-de-software, arquitetura-de-software, app, software

Pergunta óbvia que escapou por muito tempo de ser perguntada aqui no SOpt.

- *Software*
- Programa
- Aplicativo / aplicação
- *App*
- Sistema de informação

Qual a diferença?

Acredito que sei a resposta, mas vamos ver se existe concordância entre as definições e quem sabe sai algum *insight*.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Primeiro, algumas definições:

- ***Software***
  Um conjunto de instruções ou dados que operam o *hardware*.
- **Programa**
  Um conjunto de instruções que definem tarefas a serem executadas pelo computador.
- **Aplicativo / Aplicação**
  *Software* projetado para executar uma variedade de funções, com foco em tarefas.
- ***App***
  *Software* desenvolvido para uma única finalidade ou função, ou que se foca nos principais aspectos tecnológicos de dispositivos específicos.
- **Sistema de informação**
  Conjunto de componentes de *software* interrelacionados que coletam, processam, armazenam e fornecem saída das informações para fins comerciais.

Como você pode ver, existe bastante sobreposição entre conceitos.

*Software* e *programa* são intercambiáveis na maioria das situações; e todo *app* é um programa, que por conseguinte é um *software*.

Um *sistema de informação* pode ser composto de vários módulos, inclusive um ou mais *apps* e *aplicativos*. E todos estes módulos são *software*.

Comment: Você definiu programa tanto o código-fonte como o compilado, correto? E essa definição de _App_ já era usada antes do iPhone? Eu não era usuário de smartphone na época então não sei dizer, só sei que não lembro desse termo usado para celulares não-smart.

Answer (score 1):

As definições são infinitas e podem variar da mais genéricas possíveis, onde provavelmente os termos possam ser considerados sinônimos, as definições mais metódicas recorrendo a origens da grafia das palavras e o contexto de surgimento, onde provavelmente alguns dos termos possam se discriminar.

Em uma análise rápida de minha parte, sem recorrer a grandes pesquisas e focando o contexto de uso, acredito que o que mais se distingue dos demais é o termo "App", que naturalmente nos remete aos aplicativos para celular. Basta uma googlada que verá que as maiores referências são neste contexto mobile.

Segue a primeira definição que achei:
App é um apelido dado para o termo “aplicativo” (que vem do inglês application). Você também vai ouvir outras formas de chamar o App tais como: aplicativo para celular, aplicativo móvel, aplicativo mobile. 
Mas afinal, o que é um App? - Blog da Fábrica de Aplicativos https://blog.fabricadeaplicativos.com.br › fabrica › mas-afinal-o-que-e-um-app

Answer (score -1):

Software = Programa = Aplicativo = App. Na prática, tudo a mesma coisa.

Hoje em dia quando falamos "app" a maior parte das pessoas relaciona a aplicativo mobile. Mas, nada mais é do que App = Application = Aplicativo.

Já o Sistema de Informação, pode ser considerado algo mais abrangente visto que não tem haver diretamente com informáica e sim em conjunto de dados que viram informação. Ou seja, uma agenda telefônica no papel pode ser um sistema de informação.